# Does OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener die with the SharedPreference instance on which it is registered?

Tags: android, listener, sharedpreferences, onchange, android-preferences

Suppose that within *Activity A* I get a *SharedPreferences* instance called *sharedPrefs* and then I invoke the *registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener(myListener)* method on it passing an *OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener* object called *myListener* to react to changes to the preferences to which *sharedPrefs* is linked.

My question is the following: is the *onSharedPreferenceChanged* method of *myListener* invoked even if *sharedPrefs* gets out of scope, i.e. is destroyed/garbage collected, or do I need to save a reference to the object pointed by *sharedPrefs* in an *Activity A* instance variable to be sure I'll receive *changed preferences'* events during all the *Actvity A* lifecycle?

Comment: Have you tried to provoke this ? By creating 2 instances of SharePreference ?

Comment: No, I'll try it as soon as I can, in the meanwhile I asked here to see if someone gives me an answer for this maybe *more java- than android-related* question about object scope and life.

Answer (score 0):

As the instance has one registered listener, the two objects will not be garbage collected and the listener will be called.

Comment: Ok, then I have another question.. If I want to unregister the listener, how can I do that if I do not have a reference to *sharedPrefs* anymore? If it works as you said, I can not invoke *unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener* on another instance of *SharedPreferences*, say *sharedPrefs2*, right? I'll post another question for this.

Comment: You mean that what I said is correct or that I can invoke *unregister...* on a different instance than *register...*?

Comment: I think that the two sharedpref insyances are the same because you are not creating them but just getting it from a context... so you can register with a reference and unregister from another...

Comment: Just tried and it works as you said, since *getSharedPreferences* always returns the same *SharedPreferences* instance for a given preference file name.

Comment: I think that given the fact that *getSharedPreferences(java.lang.String, int)* always returns the same *SharedPreferences* object for a given String (i.e. preference file), it means that a reference to that instance must be hold into a static variable of *SharedPreferences*, so even if all of your references get out of scope, there is always a reference to the *SharedPreferences* instance of a particular preference file after you've retrieved it for the first time, right?

Comment: No matter how the SharedPreference instance is stored, static or not.. Anyway, I think that the unique instance is managed like a singleton.

Comment: Ok, but that's the way usually singletons are implemented, with a static ivar holding a reference to a unique instance.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the answer to my question may be: yes, the *OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener* dies (i.e. is not called anymore) when the *SharedPreferences* instance to which it is connected is *garbage collected*, but *it does not happen* as soon as the reference obtained with *getSharedPreferences* (or similar methods) goes out of scope, since that method returns a *singleton*, i.e. there is a static reference to the returned object, stored somewhere, that will keep the object alive. So you do not have to worry about storing the object returned by *getSharedPreferences* (although you can to avoid invoking again *getSharedPreferences*), since that methods always returns a reference to the same object. The only thing you need to worry about is storing a reference to the *OnSharedPreferenceChangeListener* objects you pass to *registerOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener* for the time when you need to unregister them in *unregisterOnSharedPreferenceChangeListener* (here you need to pass the *same instances* you passed to the *register* method, otherwise they are not *unregistered*).
Thanks to ChristopheCVB that pointed me in the right direction.